# Access element from JavaScript FileReader

Tags: javascript, file

I am trying to read a file with  in JavaScript with the File APIs.

I have the following code

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    var fileBlobs = [];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    fileBlobs.push(reader.readAsBinaryString(f));
                    console.log(reader)
        }
      }
```

It logs me this object

```
FileReader {onloadend: null, onerror: null, onabort: null, onload: null, onprogress: null…}
error: null
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
readyState: 2
result: "lat, lng, popup↵13.47262306516617336, 52.47896324136591062,    55↵13.40861762468653673, 52.54336741663770027,  44↵13.29255442595013115, 52.51117712705399754,  33↵13.38642907198692988, 52.44880630287082113,  22"
__proto__: FileReader
```

How can I access only the `result` part?

Comment: console.log(reader.result)

Comment: This doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `load` event of the `FileReader`.  In the handler, access `reader.result` or `this.result`:

```
reader.onload = function() {
    var contents = this.result;
};
```

Reading the files is an asynchronous operation.  So, you need to create a separate `FileReader` for each file.  If you want to reuse the same `FileReader`, you can't use a `for` loop.  Instead, you must wait to read the next file until after the current file is processed.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT tested, but i think it should work :)**

```
var file = document.getElementById('element-id').files;
var fr = new FileReader();
var storeBlobs = [];
fr.onload = function(e) {
  storeBlobs.push(e.target.result);
};
for(var i = 0, l = file.length; i < l; i++) {
  var content = fr.readAsText(file[i]);
}
```

File returns an array of objects which can be then manipulated trough FileReader object with onload method. If user loads more than one file we want to process all of it, and we will do that with for loop. I emphasize that this code is not tested, but it should work.

We can, if we assume that user will load one file only make file object to behave like this with replacing first line of code with this:

`var file = document.getElementById('element-id').files[0];`

Comment: Please try to put comments or an explanation of why it works

Comment: @meneldal This code is simple and self explanatory, but i guess that you're right, some people need more info, and thats ok. Thanks and i appreciate that you mention that.

Comment: People who read your answer might not be proficient in whatever language is used so it's considered good practice to explain as much as possible.